# Is there a way to average from filtering specific data from an importrange?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I'm working on a different Google Sheets spreadsheet to input data (film details such as English Title, Original Title, Release Date, Rating, Country of Origin and a Link), while on the one I'm analyzing the data I managed to use `importrange` successfully.

Here is the code I used successfully in order to get the average rating of a country's list of movies:

```
=AVERAGE(IMPORTRANGE("LINK_TO_INPUT_DATA_GOOGLE_SHEETS", CONCAT(A1:A, "!D1:D")))
```

This average is outputted to column C, while the name of the Country (which is also the name of the sheet for `importrange`) is in Column A.

I want to create a similar query but for movies that have the Country of Origin matching the Country from Column A (Any movie that has multiple countries of origin are inputted with the first one in the spreadsheet and copied over in all the other countries of origin's respective sheets).

I tried using the `QUERY` from Google Sheets to make my resultset, but in the best case scenario, it gives the same result as the previous average, while in the worst case scenario it just gives out errors. Here is my latest attempt at the query:

```
=AVERAGE(QUERY (IMPORTRANGE("LINK_TO_INPUT_DATA_GOOGLE_SHEETS", A1:A), "SELECT Col4 WHERE Col5="&A1&""))
```

As far as I can tell, this should work, but at the moment it says it cannot find the range or sheet for the imported range.

Any help is deeply appreciated!

EDIT:

Here's a link of the input sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bopmJu7Av71sCh8iUoG20WubGL9ssx09dOnBZnys4Ko/edit?usp=sharing

Here's a link of the analysis spreadsheet (the query should be in the MOVIES sheet):
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-hfQdqvDWXXtGR2fmTy-lZEOtp9sdxkvoget4toi1W4/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure If I got you right:
- you want: import the average of the ratings (column 4) by movie title (column 1) where the country matches your current column A?

If so it can simply done with queries, especially if you include the average in the query as well. But you need to include all columns you use in the importrange:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("https://...", "Syria!A1:E"),"SELECT AVG(Col4) WHERE Col5='"&A2&"' LABEL AVG(Col4) ''")
```

Explanation: `group by` will aggregate all columns by the column you declared as being used as average.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. It gives out "Evaluation of function AVERAGE caused a divide by zero error."

Comment: I want to import the average Ratings (Column 4) where Column 5 equals the name of the Sheet.

Comment: For example: I want to average all the movies from the India sheet where the Country of Origin is India and not others like the US, UK or others.

Comment: @RusPaulAdrian: Sorry, my bad, the `AVERAGE` in the beginning should not be there. I updated the query. It should work now.

Comment: Have you updated the query? It gives out the same error. Is there a way to show you directly through photos the situation in my Google Sheets?

Comment: Perhaps I am missing something here... Have a look at an example spreadsheet. Its all in one sheet, so instead of IMPORTRANGE I just query the same table but it should show how the formula works: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QHyLJt_-_ud9hF4QxKo1k-N8C3FVb47Xg-QSaGZjYOk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Here is a viewable link to my input data spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bopmJu7Av71sCh8iUoG20WubGL9ssx09dOnBZnys4Ko/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: The second link is to my analysis spreadsheet and the main sheet I want to use for this project is Movies: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-hfQdqvDWXXtGR2fmTy-lZEOtp9sdxkvoget4toi1W4/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I want to get the average Rating for the movies with the Country of Origin (Column E), equals the Sheet's name. For example, in the Syria Sheet I want the average rating of all the rows where Country of Origin = "Syria".

Comment: Should be easy, just change the group by column. How about you post the structure of your sheets, e.g. as screenshot or as public link to an example file? That would remove the guessing which columns contain what value.

Comment: I just posted 2 viewing links above in this conversation stream ^

Comment: @RusPaulAdrian I believe you have an error in your importrange, because you need to refer to the exact sheet you want to look up. I updated the example spreadsheet file, have a look: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QHyLJt_-_ud9hF4QxKo1k-N8C3FVb47Xg-QSaGZjYOk/edit#gid=0 This is now working with the file you provided but with a manual reference to the page.

Comment: Happy to help :-)

Answer (score 0):

this is the correct syntax:

```
=AVERAGE(QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("ID_OR_URL"; "Sheet1!A1:A"); "SELECT Col4 WHERE Col5='"&A1&"'"; 0))
```

Comment: Unfortunately when I replace the URL it can't find the range or sheet. I can't understand the problem, since the first IMPORTRANGE example I gave works as intended.